# Error in strings.xml: invalid symbol 'continue'

Tags: android

In my strings.xml file I have

```
<string name="continue">Continue</string>
```

I can't build my project because of the error: "Invalid symbol: 'continue'". Why I can't use such a name?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It's because `continue` is a reserved symbol in Java, so you cannot use it as a name for any object in your XML files or Java code.

The reason this is a problem is that the XML defined in your project is translated into Java code that the Dalvik VM can understand. So, your code above translates into the following in R.java:

```
public final class R {
    public static final class string {
        public static final int continue=0x7f040000;
    }
}
```

The problem is more obvious when examining the (would-be) generated code.

See [list of reserved Java symbols](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) for others to avoid.

Comment: thanks so much for the hint. I've been trying to use a continue button in my app with the name continue, and now I know why my R.java could not be generated.

Comment: So is there any work around? I am facing same problem but in my case string is "void" i can't avoid writing it.

Comment: The string *contents* can be a keyword, but the *'name' attribute* cannot be a keyword. So, `<string name="void">Void</string>` won't work, but `<string name="lblvoid">Void</string>` is fine.

Answer (score 6):

"continue" is a Java keyword and the R.java would not compile.

```
public static final int continue=0x7f040001;
```

the above code would cause an "Syntax error on token "continue", invalid VariableDeclaratorId" error.