# Android Error while generating the XML file

Tags: android

I'am trying to create an XML file as follows. But I'am getting the below error

```
Unparsed aapt error(s) check the Console for output
```

In the cosole, I'am getting the below error

```
[2012-02-11 20:39:08 - TEST] res\layout\final.xml:0: error: invalid symbol: 'final'
```

My XML file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="#000044">

<TableRow>

<TextView
android:text="Col 1"
android:width ="80px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
/>

<TextView
android:text="Col 2"
android:width ="80px"
/>

<TextView
android:text="Col 3"
android:width ="80px"
/>

<TextView
android:text="Col 4"
android:width ="80px"
/>

<TextView
android:text="Col 5"
android:width ="120px"
/>

</TableRow>

<TableRow>
<TextView />

</TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```

Please help

Thanks

KR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`final` is java's reserved keyword. So instead **final**, change it to something like **layout_final**

for more info, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850069/error-in-strings-xml-invalid-symbol-continue)

Comment: Nice catch. I've been staring at that code for 5 minutes now and didn't think of that. +1

Comment: Thanks Waqas. yes I have set it as answer now. Sorry for the delay as I'am new to Stackoverflow :-)