# android xml file invalid symbol: 'do', the xml file is from decompiled apk code

Tags: java, android, xml, apk, recompile

I know "do"  is a reserved symbol in Java from this question [Error in strings.xml: invalid symbol 'continue'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850069/error-in-strings-xml-invalid-symbol-continue)
so you cannot use it as a name for any object in your XML files or Java code.

But why decompiling a apk produces a invalid xml file? What could be the reason and how to solve the problem so I can rebuild the apk.

part of the xml file:

```
    <public type="attr" name="d_" id="0x7f010093" />
    <public type="attr" name="da" id="0x7f010094" />
    <public type="attr" name="db" id="0x7f010095" />
    <public type="attr" name="dc" id="0x7f010096" />
    <public type="attr" name="dd" id="0x7f010097" />
    <public type="attr" name="de" id="0x7f010098" />
    <public type="attr" name="df" id="0x7f010099" />
    <public type="attr" name="dg" id="0x7f01009a" />
    <public type="attr" name="dh" id="0x7f01009b" />
    <public type="attr" name="di" id="0x7f01009c" />
    <public type="attr" name="dj" id="0x7f01009d" />
    <public type="attr" name="dk" id="0x7f01009e" />
    <public type="attr" name="dl" id="0x7f01009f" />
    <public type="attr" name="dm" id="0x7f0100a0" />
    <public type="attr" name="dn" id="0x7f0100a1" />
    <public type="attr" name="do" id="0x7f0100a2" />
    <public type="attr" name="dp" id="0x7f0100a3" />
    <public type="attr" name="dq" id="0x7f0100a4" />
    <public type="attr" name="dr" id="0x7f0100a5" />
    <public type="attr" name="ds" id="0x7f0100a6" />
    <public type="attr" name="dt" id="0x7f0100a7" />
    <public type="attr" name="du" id="0x7f0100a8" />
```

Comment: The file is obfuscated specifically to slow down decompilation attempts.

Comment: @laalto what to do about it? Any suggestion?

Comment: Don't reverse other people's apps. Write your own.

Comment: @laalto I am trying to run multi instances of the same app for convenience.